# Burgers' Equation 'Shocks' Not matching the characteristics

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics, hyperbolic-equations

[Album to view all the images that are described below.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3ILD.jpg)

I have am using Burgers' Equation with the initial condition of a Gaussian.

The blue curve is the initial function before any time has passed, and the green curve is when the shock first appears. I let more time pass, calculating the shock at each point in time using the equal area rule.

When I plot the shocks that are found on the characteristic plot, I would assume that the shock would first appear where the characteristics first cross. My problem is that it happens at the correct x position, but the time position is wrong (the graph below is an time vs position graph).  I have calculated this with a program, but my partner got the same result by hand (note here that I did not do the calculation by hand, and have no idea how he found it).

Why is the times not syncing with the characteristics? Am I just not understanding shocks correctly here?

Comment: At the very least you will need to show us your code; preferably also your partner's hand computations. It is quite likely that you completely understood the shock formation, just programmed poorly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving my problem myself. I had a few issues, but the main one being my time variable was being implemented in a wrong way. The finished product can be found [here](https://github.com/wesleybowman/shocksInBurgersEquation), write up is included, along with a Windows version of the program so that no python is needed.